# Opto-isolator voltage

Tags: opto-isolator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvd2QA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

- The opto isolator emitter has a constant -3.2 V .
- The opto isolator collector is pulled down by 512 marked resistor.
- When the opto isolator input is activated I measure -1.2 volts at the collector.
- It needs -3.3 V to be considered pulled down by the ARM CPU

This is how the board is made but "not by me."

I have just studied the chips on the board to try to understand how it is supposed to work.

Why is there a loss of 2V over the opto isolator?

This is a new card. It has never worked. I bought it years ago so no warranty.

I am trying to learn how electronics work all by myself. It is hard to get it all together.

Comment: Does the 5.1k pull to ground? And really 3.3V on emitter? If so the problem is clear, but please make sure the details are right so we don't have to guess.

Comment: There is enough info now. Voting to reopen. And the OP seems to know there is one problem and that is the reason why it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure with the collector connectetd to GND?

Comment: Magnus Andersson - Hi, Thanks for adding a partial schematic. Briefly: (a) A resistor marked 512 (is there something before the "5" too?) is not 5.12 k. In this case it may not matter, but I suggest that you measure the value if unsure. (b) The schematic is clearly incomplete e.g. there is a component across the optocoupler's photodiode. Also the input to the photodiode is not 12 V (as that would damage it). That uncertainty about schematic accuracy may put off some readers. Can you improve it? (c) More context would help e.g. did this ever work? (d) Are you sure optocoupler emitter isn't Gnd?

Comment: as  you said @SamGibson the emitter was ground and the pin is pulled high by the resistor i revised the drawing again after measuring it  it is strange that it wont go low

Comment: @Mike the collector was connected to 3.2 v so pulling the pin high =) i need it to pull low   (i thought i rememberd my measurments   but clearly not =)

Comment: @justme i think this time its correct i am a novice on this  usually i rebuild cars and cnc machines but love electronics so i am trying to learn

Comment: it think i have solved it.  the pull up resistor is 5.1k but in the spec for the arm cpu it is supposed to be between 30 and 50 Kohms.   to be able to go low as it has to go below 0.8 volts!